# Permission issue in Linkedin API

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkedin-api

I am using C# language and ASP.NET framework for linkedin integration

While authorization I have passed r_liteprofile,r_emailaddress within the scope and when I am trying to get the data of user I am facing the following issues:

1. When trying to get the data of the user using the API v1 `(https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,picture-url,email-address)?oauth2_access_token={accessToken}&format=json)` I am getting the 410 (Gone) error. { It was working previously}.
2. When I am trying to get the data of the user using API v2 `(https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token={accesstoken}&format=json)` I am getting the 403 (Forbidden access) error.

For the purpose of **authorization**:

1. Previously I was using `(https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={apiKey}&redirect_uri={redirectURL}&state={uniquestringkey}&scope=r_basicprofile,r_emailaddress)`
2. I also tried using the following authorization `(https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={apiKey}&redirect_uri={redirectURL}&state={uniquestringkey}&scope=r_liteprofile,r_emailaddress )`

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: Are you url encoding the data in the URL (e.g. `redirectURL`)?

Comment: Yes, I am using url encoding, I also tried not using the url encoding. But none of them seems to work. Getting the same issue.